# Get reference of the ejb3 local business inside mdb

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

What's the best way to get EJB3, EJBLocal Object in MDB Class ?

Thanks.

Comment: Let me clarify little bit, My EJB Component is located in SAME Project or you can say that it's in Same EAR. So if i use @EJB in MDB is that all right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is **injection**

```
@MessageDriven
public class MsgBean implements MessageListener {
@EJB
private ServiceBean service;

    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        service.process(msg);
    }
}
```